# Combine specific files and put it in a single file python

Tags: python, file, concatenation

I'm new to python.
I have two files text1.txt and text2.txt in my directory. I need to combine the data from text1 and text2 and print the result in result.txt.

For Example:

text1.txt

```
a                              
b               
c
```

text2.txt

```
aa                                                                                                            bb
cc
```

result.txt

```
a
b
c
aa
bb
cc
```

(All one below the other)

Now, I know a script to combine all the files .txt by declaring the global

```
import glob
files = glob.glob( '*.txt' )

with open( 'result.txt', 'w' ) as result:
    for file_ in files:
        for line in open( file_, 'r' ):
            result.write( line )
```

but I have a lot of files that end with .txt and I want specific files.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a list of the files you want to copy from.

```
files = ['text1.txt', 'text2.txt']

with open('result.txt', 'w') as result:
    for file_ in files:
        for line in open(file_, 'r'):
            result.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will avoid parsing the newlines, so may be faster as long as each file fits into memory and ends with a newline.

```
from itertools import chain

files = ['text1.txt', 'text2.txt']
with outfile as open('result.txt', 'w'):
    outfile.write(chain.from_iterable(open(f).read() for f in files)
```